# How to set Access-Control-Max-Age for flask_cors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-cors, max-age

In my flask application, I need to set `Access-Control-Max-Age`. What is the correct syntax for it?

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder='./build') 
CORS(app)
```

reference: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `flask_cors.CORS` section, the `max_age` part.

> **max_age (timedelta, integer, string or None)** –
>
> The maximum time for which this CORS request maybe cached. This value is set as the Access-Control-Max-Age header.

According to the docs, you may need to init your `CORS` with this parameter.

```
CORS(app, max_age=3600)
```

Comment: It is correct thanks. I am not sure why it was not working in my case. I have a long call with I tried to add `timeout: 10000000` on request header and also `max_age=10000000` but its failing to accept response.